# Checking if a paperclip attachment exists within a view.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, if-statement, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Check whether a Paperclip attachment exists:
I'm trying to see if the attachment has selected a file/image then something will happen like this new view to appear. So after i click browse select an Image I want something to happen!! Thanks!

Nothing happens when i do this code!

home view:

```rails
<% if @post.image.present? %>
            <%= render 'posts' %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: Is there an alternative you'd like to see if there is no image uploaded? (so that something happens in the event that there is no image present)

Comment: i would actually prefer not to see an alt image. Thats another problem as it outputs missing before i try to upload a photo. I want to remove the "missing" message as well

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `exists?` or `file?` methods.
`exists?`: will check if the file actually exist (slow)
`file?`: will only check if there is a value in db (faster).

```
<% if @post.image.exists? %>
    <%= render 'posts' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I believe it should be .exists? and not .exist?  So `<% if @post.image.exists? %>` for the example above.